# How to change the onload event of body after condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the onload event of the body once a certain condition is met.

In my case the condition is that I first have to let the page load and get the current onload event and compare that to a certain string if it returns true I will then replace it with a different function to assign to the onload event.

Is this even possible since when the page loads my new onload event will practically do nothing so im guessing is that i have to change it before it reaches the body.

This was something I got from my previous question. I also added a few things:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var x = new String(document.body.onload);
x = x.replace(/ /gi,"");
x = x.replace("functiononload(event){","");
x = x.replace("}","");
alert(x);
//what i want to do after i checked the old event if it is equal to something.
window.onload = function() {
newfunction();
x();
}();
});

<body onload="wewewe();">
```

Comment: This is a bad idea.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: This is a really bad idea. If you are using jquery anyway, why don't you just bind to `load` event using that?

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're very new to javascript and jquery. There's nothing wrong with that.  It looks as if you're confused, though, when you'd want to use 'on load.'  The `$(document).ready(` is effectively the same thing as body.onload.  If you want items to happen sequentially, then you should simply put them sequentially in that ready function.  As others have said, what's the end goal?

Comment: @SLaks the thing here is that there are certain instances that i need to change the onload event of the body. thus the need for me to first retrieve the current event of the onload and check if it is a certain function and if it is that then i need to change it to another function that will have the old function appended on it. is there really no way for me to do this? thank you

Comment: @loopers: You should design your page such that you don't need to do that in the first place.  Move the whole thing to an external script and use variables.

Comment: @SLaks the page is dynamic and the onload varies on the template uploaded by the user thus i need to this little script, though i am still open to other options.

Comment: @loopers: Make the onload use a variable or function from your script.

Comment: @SLaks variable? would you provide an example. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply use :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (condition) {
        // do something
    }
    else {
        // do something other
    }
});
```

`body.onload` and `$(document).ready()` are almost identical.